# Unable to delete a folder with SHFileOperation

Tags: winapi

I'm unable to delete a folder in Windows with the following code:

```
SHFILEOPSTRUCT shfo = {
    NULL,
    FO_DELETE,
    path,
    NULL,
    FOF_SILENT | FOF_NOERRORUI | FOF_NOCONFIRMATION,
    FALSE,
    NULL,
    NULL };

SHFileOperation(&shfo);
```

I need to use `SHFileOperation` instead of `RemoveDirectory` because I need to delete non-empty folders.

However, the function fails even if the value in `path` points to an empty local folder with full control of Everyone user, is double-null terminated (as requested by [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759795%28VS.85%29.aspx)), has no system, hidden or read only attribute...

Unfortunately the function does not return an error code (returns zero if successful, or nonzero otherwise) and calling `GetLastError` returns `ERROR_SUCCESS`...

Where is the error?

Comment: Which error values does it return? That'd probably give you an idea (or at least stop anyone trying to answer this having to guess every possible way that an API might fail to delete a folder).

Comment: @Leo: unfortunately the function returns zero if successful, or nonzero otherwise...

Comment: It's documented as returning more than just boolean success: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762164%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Leo: d'oh, that wasn't mentioned on the offline version of MSDN I'm using (the one that comes with Visual Studio 2005).

Comment: I've run into the same thing in the past. :) Always worth checking online if you get stuck with an API, not just for updated docs but for the Community Content comments people sometimes add about common problems or errors in the docs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Solved...

The `path` variable wasn't actually double-null terminated because I used `wcscpy_s` that fills the string buffer (that I had previously filled with zeros) [with the 0xFD value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235389.aspx) after the null char...

Comment: haha, had the same issue, even though I thought I was double null terminating.. I wasn't